# CSS- Display things in line

Tags: html, css

i need to display few similar images and text in one line, like here:

http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_4126372791396608500.jpg

I was thinking about using some li ul or inline-block  but noone of it work correctly for me. I am probably doing something really wrong.

I have to say i am declarate li ul for something else before:

```
li{
    padding: 0 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul{
    list-style-position: inside;   
    list-style-type: none;         
}
```

My try of it is here:
CSS:

```
.undernews{   /* This is background */
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-image: url("images/under_news_bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 121px;
    width:  987px;
    display: table;
}
.sellgames{    /* This
    line-height: 2;
    width 987px;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="undernews"></div>
<ul>
  <li><span class="sellgames">Counter-Strike 1.6 Steam <br><img src="images/CSsteam.png"></span</li>
  <li><span class="sellgames">Counter-Strike 1.6 Steam <br><img src="images/CSsteam.png"></span</li>
</ul>
```

Can somebody write me down how it should be ? Or how can i fix it without ediiting existing li and ul ?

Comment: Have you tried `li { float:left;}`?

Answer (score 1):

You have failures in your HTML code, so try to change to this first:

```
<div class="undernews">
<ul>
  <li><span class="sellgames">Counter-Strike 1.6 Steam <img src="images/CSsteam.png"></span></li>
  <li><span class="sellgames">Counter-Strike 1.6 Steam <img src="images/CSsteam.png"></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS looks like:

```
.undernews ul li {
   display: inline-block;
   list-style-type: none;
   padding-right: 0px;
}

.undernews ul li img {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 60px;
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ctHLj/)

Comment: Yea i tryed something really similar as u wrote here before, it do THIS: http://funedit.com/andurit/newnew/ with my page

Comment: I try it, and didnt help much :(

Comment: You see, this solution works. For the rest of your code, no idea, i cannot see it. Seems like you are new to HTML/CSS, so try a bunch of tutorials first to get clear what selectors are, and when to use ids and classes.

Answer (score 0):

try this example , for a simple horizontal list

**CSS CODE**

```
#navcontainer ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}

#navcontainer ul li { display: inline; }

#navcontainer ul li a
{
text-decoration: none;
padding: .2em 1em;
color: #fff;
background-color: #036;
}

#navcontainer ul li a:hover
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #369;
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Eggs</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cheese</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Fruit</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example is PERFECT man, really help me. But i still have some problem after my edit. I add there images and text, and instead of display it in line as that menu it looks like this: http://funedit.com/andurit/newnew/
Is there a chance you can help me to fix it?

Comment: look the @askrufus answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS like following code.

```
div.undernews ul li {
   display: inline-block;
   *display: inline;
   zoom: 1;
   list-style-type: none;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   padding: 10px;
}

div.undernews ul li img {
    display: block;
}
span.sellgames{
    line-height: 2;
    height: auto;
    position: static;
    text-align: left;
}
```

***Preview >> [Minecraft Temp](http://www.madhushankarathnayake.com/temp/Minecraft%20Server%20Status.htm)***